# Android Java: Unable to selectively highlight rows in a ListView via onScroll listener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have another blocker as I study Android Development.
This time my problem is when I wanted to "selectively" highlight a row in a ListView populated by data from an adapter.

This ListView is actually within a dialog, and purpose is to show a list of friends, where user can multi-select and highlight it as he selects.
The selected values by the way, is stored in an ArrayList "arr_FriendsShare" so that the next time he opens the listview, rows will be highlighted (via onScrollListener) for those previously selected.

What is currently happening, only the "recently" or "last" clicked row/item is highlighted; and seems to be clearing all the previously highlighted rows.

I cannot understand why it is behaving that way, as row's value is successfully stored to/removed from arr_FriendsShare ArrayList, as I click on it.

Below is my listener codes, and thanks in advance for the usual help:

```
    //Item click listener for Select Friends ListView
    listview_SelectFriends.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
             long arg3) 
       {
             String friends_ListItemSelected = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 

             if(!arr_FriendsShare.contains(friends_ListItemSelected)){
                 arr_FriendsShare.add(friends_ListItemSelected);
             }
             else{
                 removeItemFromArrayListString(Main.this, arr_FriendsShare, friends_ListItemSelected);
             }
       }
    });

    listview_SelectFriends.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { 
            for (int i = firstVisibleItem; i < (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem); i++) {
                String listViewItemText = view.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                if(arr_FriendsShare.contains(listViewItemText)){
                    ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_light));
                    view.setSelector(cd);
                }
                else if(arr_FriendsShare.contains(listViewItemText)){
                    ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    view.setSelector(cd);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**Additional Code Block:**

```
    ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    String jsonURL = <SOME URL HERE>;
    stringArray = Global.getStringArrayFromJSON(Main.this, jsonURL, "friends", "FriendUsername");

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list_layout, null);

    ListView listview_SelectFriends = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_Friends);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray);
    listview_SelectFriends.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray);
```

to

```
// Define this at class level as --> private FriendsAdapter adapter = null;
adapter = new FriendsAdapter(Main.this, stringArray);
```

add this method in your activity

```
private void setResetSelection(int index, boolean setSelection){
    View v = listview_SelectFriends.getChildAt(index);
    if(v != null){
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        if(setSelection)
            name.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        else
            name.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
    }
}
```

and create a new class as

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<String> mFriends;
private ArrayList<String> mSelectedFriends = new ArrayList<String>();

public GoodPeopleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> friends) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mFriends= friends;
}

public void setSelectedFriends(ArrayList<String> selectedFriends){
    mSelectedFriends = selectedFriends;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFriends.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mFriends.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    String name = mFriends.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(name);

    if(mSelectedFriends.contains(name))
        holder.name.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red) // red is in color xml by default, change according to your choice

    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name;
}
}
```

Add following line at the end of method `onItemClick`

```
adapter.setSelectedFriends(arr_FriendsShare);
```

Add this in the if part of `onItemClick`

```
setResetSelection(position, true);
```

and this in else part

```
setResetSelection(position, false);
```

Also create a new xml layout with name `row_layout` with a textview with id `name`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions man. just to answer your question regarding why am i removing an array on the else routine. The reason for that actually is so that when the user clicks the 2nd time on the same row (which he earlier selected), it should remove that item from the array and therefore "unselecting" the friend from the list. think of it as unchecking an alreaday marked checkbox.

to add, the statement onScroll is i think not similar from the onClick. as the one onScroll should only be responsible for highlighting the ListView items that are already in the array.

Comment: the statement onScroll is i think not similar from the onClick. as the one onScroll should only be responsible for highlighting the ListView items that are already in the array. not interacting with the array.

I would have wanted to edit or remove the onScroll routine, but can't find a better alternative yet on how to highlight ListView rows based from an array e.g. ArrayList<String>

Comment: Why don't you put the logic from method `onScroll` in `getView`?

Comment: hmmm... I can try that. do you have code samples for getView?

Comment: Are you using custom adapter? If yes, can you post that code block?

Comment: I edited the original question and included the "Additional Code Block" section. i am using ArrayAdapter<String>, let me know what you think. thanks.

Comment: thanks for the code, and i think it will work but not for my specific code. this is because, my listview does not have a custom layout and does not have a TextView. it is just a plain ListView with rows populated from adapter. :-(

giving you a +1 point, but will not mark it as an answer. thanks.

Comment: Thats why I asked you to create a custom adapter.  :D