# Handling events on individual textviews in a listview extended from list activity

Tags: android

I have an activity which extends a list activity. The activity extracts data in the form of json array from the web server. The json array which is returned contains data in groups of 3 name/value pairs. I display the data in 3 text views one in each views in the listview from the simple adapter. The onclickitem event is working wenever i click on the listview item but wat i want is to be able to define different events for clicking on different text views which are a part of the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Add your onClickListener on the individual textviews, not on your whole View bound by the adapter.

```js
textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{...})
```

Comment: Can't do that because he is not using a custom adapter.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options

1. Create custom adapter for this and handle the desired action in `getView()` method.
2. Get the current selected item view using `getChildAt()`; using this view you can get the 3 text views and perform an action.

But as per my experience and for the sake of more flexibility first option is much better. I have answered a question here which has a sample custom adapter, if you want you can have a look.

[Android Java: Unable to selectively highlight rows in a ListView via onScroll listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725605/android-java-unable-to-selectively-highlight-rows-in-a-listview-via-onscroll-li/27725728#27725728)

Comment: I knw its not you, someone else did. Could have left a comment at least.

Comment: Ok but mate i was able to accomplish the task from the onlistitemclicked event from view.getviewbyid

Comment: I want to develop an android app which has a feature that enables a user to search videos from the internet by entering the topic of video in the edit text. How to get it done

Comment: If my answer helped you then can you accept  it as an answer? Let discuss your app on chat.

Comment: Oh I am sorry you are not eligible for chat yet. Searching of video means?? Using google/bing search??

Comment: user should be able to enter a video topic and related videos appear

Comment: You will have to use some search engine for that, otherwise from where you will search data in internet.